# How do I recover the SHA of a reverted commit?

Tags: git, revert

Say I have a revert `"Revert "Commit B""`, is there a way to get the SHA-1 of `"Commit B"`?

I was hoping if it was possible to get the SHA-1 of any reverted commit like in a merge. Since the parent of a merge commit is booth the SHA-1 of the two merged commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git revert` command is a functionality provided for convenience. It finds out what the target commit changes, apply it reversely and creates a new commit. The new commit isn't technically special to Git compared to any other regular commits, though its changes is the exact reverse of the reverted commit.

Despite that, if you use `git revert <commit>` directly, the auto-generated commit message *does* contain the SHA of the source commit, for example:

```
commit fdcfd9f4c59a686651b7935c188917099f653e16
Author: iBug <redacted>
Date:   Thu Dec 5 09:31:53 2019 +0000

    Revert "Limit landing screen height"

    This reverts commit 444e34cceffec12716af61dd94d0ca62a35e2564.
```

However, if you edited the commit message and removed the SHA from it, you're probably unlucky and have to find another way out.

Comment: I guess I will have to find another way. Thanks for the answer.